# Will the ip address for a notebook on colab virtual instance change over time?

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, google-colaboratory

Will the ip address of the virtual machine on which one colab notebook runs change over time? Is the ip address a static one or dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

It changes!  Verified yesterday, within the same day it changed.

We were looking to white list IP in AWS, but it isn't that simple.

Answer (score 0):

They are dynamic.

If you need to know the IP ranges for whitelisting or something similar, you need to consider all Google IP range. If so, [check this article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322).

In short, Google publishes:

- https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json: IP ranges that Google announces to the internet
- https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json: Customer-usable IP address ranges

Obviously, this lists are not static (they may change), so you'll need to script your rules using this sources to assure your list is kept updated.