# Do I need to manually rotate ip address to avoid being detected when running codes on Google Colab?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, ip, google-colaboratory

I'm wondering is it necessary to manually rotate IP addresses to avoid being detected when I run codes on Colab? I learned that Google Colab will automatically change the IP address of the virtual machines ([Will the ip address for a notebook on colab virtual instance change over time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786670/will-the-ip-address-for-a-notebook-on-colab-virtual-instance-change-over-time)) , so, does that mean I don't need to change IP by myself? Then if I continue using Colab to scrape webpages, do I still have the risk of being detected?

More information: I have already rotated user-agent for every 300 requests, and my script takes around 5 seconds to scrape one webpage, which contains 2 requests for each loop (since I'm using Selenium, there won't be any high-frequency requests involved).

Comment: It's a very open ended question which totally depends on the website you're scraping. Some websites are very sensitive about web-scrapers, some aren't and some are extremely aggressive.

Comment: Hi Granitosaurus thanks for your reply! I'm scraping Zara, and it seems this website is not that sensitive to scrapers? At least till now, it doesn't prevent me to do anything. But my question is, does Google Colab automatically help us rotate IP addresses? Because based on my understanding, we won't need to rotate again if Colab has already done so. Thx!

Comment: Honestly even if google changes IPs I'd adivise getting couple of proxies. If your target is relatively friendly (most e-commerce shops like Zara are) then just having few data center proxies would make the whole experience much more smooth and safer. Cloud hosts aren't too keen on hosting web-scrapers so by using proxy not only protects yourself from bans but also from being suspended from your cloud provider.

Comment: Super convincing and helpful suggestions! I'll take it! Thank you!